# Running Markdownify through Composer on php WAMP server (win10)?

Tags: php, windows, wamp, markdown, wampserver

I'm trying to include and use [Markdownify](https://github.com/Elephant418/Markdownify) in my PHP script on a local server in windows 10, but it does not work.

- I have [WAMP64](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download-wampserver-64bits/) server installed, on which I run my PHP files locally.
- I've downloaded [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) and installed it.
- During Composer installation I picked php.exe from my WAMP64 server when prompted.
- In a CMD I have then entered "composer require pixel418/markdownify", the command was recognized and completed.
- Now I try to define in my PHP code:

> $converter = new Markdownify\Converter;

but it does not work. Instead I get the error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Markdownify\Converter' not found in D:\wamp64\www\mysite\investigate.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\wamp64\www\mysite\investigate.php on line 16

Any hint on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add these lines in your script so PHP knows where to get the classes from

```
namespace Markdownify;
use Markdownify\Converter;
```